# How to stop bubbling without access to children's click handlers and stopPropagation call? (clickable components inside clickable wrapper)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, children, event-bubbling, stoppropagation

I need help, advice, moral support.. :)

I take part in developing the UI library as a trainee and right now have a task to create a component like a card - it’s a simple wrapper with some styles for any other components.
What’s kind of problem here? Classic - js bubbling.
This wrapper should be clickable, but some children could be clickable too (with different click handlers).

```
<div onClick={doSomething}>
  {props.children}   // it could be anything, absolutely, both clickable and non-clickable
</div>
```

I tried `e.preventDefault()` in click handler on card with the condition that `e.target !== e.currentTarget`, but this way makes a major part of card non-clickable through content like text, images, etc.

I know about `e.stopPropagation()` and it works pretty well, but I don’t have direct access to children.
I mean I don’t know what structure (nesting), kind of tags, and behavior they will have. Also, there could be a case without clickable children at all.
So I can't add this call on my side (I think so. Maybe I'm wrong) - what could I else do in that case to stop bubbling on children's clicks?
Is there any alternative way?

[example of such cards on pinterest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0wJR.png)

Comment: You say "e.target !== e.currentTarget" makes "makes a major part of card non-clickable" but stopping bubbling is exactly that, ignoring clicks from child elements. So I don't understand your problem. You want to ignore click events from children but only if those children don't have click handlers?

Comment: @gforce301 Yes, you're right - for example, if I have click on some button inside this card I need to stop bubbling and run the action applicable for this button only (ex. open modal window), not for the card. But, if I have click on children like text or image I need to 'pass' this click through them and run action applicable for the card (ex. go to link).

Comment: That is not to say that if the handlers are added with reactjs, that the framework does not have some way to get that information.